# how to Retrieve an Image from SQLite DB?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How to retrieve an image stored in Sqlite table?

the table looks like the following:

```
public class ImageInDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test01.db";
private static final String MP_TABLE_NAME = "MPImage";

ImageInDB (Context context) { 
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}// end of 

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + MP_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " img BLOB  " +
            ");" );
}
```

Now, how should the method that retrieve the image llok like?? below is my attempt:

```
public ??? getMP_RPY(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT img FROM MPImage WHERE "+
                                                BaseColumns._ID+" = "+
                                                Long.toString(id), null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    ???? r = c.getDouble(0);
    return r;       
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);

byte[] bb = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.ImageField));

myImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length));
```

**OR**

Please check [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html)

Comment: what is the value of "MyBaseColumn"?? i mean what should i substitute it with??

Answer (score 6):

Don't store image into the SQLite Database. Store the path to the image instead. Or if you **REALLY** want to store the image into the database, then learn basic SQ Lite.